# Want to make code for inactive or idle user time in Python when he did not show any movement on screen and keyboard and mouse through

Tags: python, django, project-management, time-tracking, task-management

I am student and I am making an app regarding tracking time activity. So please help me to give an solution. I am finding out from last 4 days regarding the hints or code . I got one solution of my friend . but i am confuse that how to use this. If i use this and store that time so how could i make an object and api so i can display this time in frontend side.

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    from ctypes import *
    
    class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('cbSize', c_uint),
            ('dwTime', c_int),
        ]
        
    def get_idle_duration():
        lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
        lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
        if windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo)):
            millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
            return millis / 1000.0
        else:
            return 0
else:
    def get_idle_duration():
        return 0
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    while True:
        duration = get_idle_duration()
        print('User idle for %.2f seconds.' % duration)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I am expecting that please help me to solve my solution. I am student and I am learning this. I am expecting an output like total idle time of computer is 1 hr or 2 hr . I already made code for tracking time for task/project time.